# A successor to InstallJammer?

Tags: deployment, installation, multiplatform

I have been using [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) for some time, but it's development is now discontinued. Does anyone know a good successor to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a successor, but there are a lot of alternatives. Here is a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Answer (score 1):

[BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) is a multiplatform installer alternative to InstallJammer. It is commercial but we have discounts for small companies/solo developers and free licenses for open source projects (Disclaimer, I am the author of InstallBuilder)

Comment: do you do trials? Could I be able to produce working installers to make a comparison with the existing process?

Comment: Yes, the evaluation version you can download is fully functional